# Changing the default save file format in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

I constantly use TeXShop to create plain text files, so I prefer to change its default save file format from TeX file to Plain Text (.txt) or the last saved file format. Is it possible?

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to change the default Save extension in TeXShop. It's meant to be mostly used for creating .tex files which are plain text files too. Of course you can always create an applescript macrowhich will change it after it's been saved.

Comment: There was a "save as" macro by Michael Sharpe available some time ago from now drop[dead]box account, perhaps one of the long time users here may be able to dig a copy out of their archives ?

Comment: There is a link to the macro at <[http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2012-June/049198.html](http://tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2012-June/049198.html)>. While it doesn't do what you want it to do (it's meant to serialize the output names of files) if you are reasonably good at AppleScript you shold be able to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @HerbSchulz that was the dead link I referred to and now see you were the one to first reply at the time so I guess you should know how it behaved from a copy (I did not see a reference to serialize in the early tread) can you paste a snippet in an answer ?

Comment: @KJO : it wasn’t dead when I clicked on it. I got a .dmg with the macro .plist and documentation.

Comment: @HerbSchulz Using three different machines here all with different browsers (I.E. firefox edge) the dropbox link gives me 404 (page not found) admittedly they are all switching the old http to https but no joy. Hence frequent site recommendation not to use links when a short paste or description of content is possible.

Comment: I knew the "save as" macro link before I posted this question, and it  also gave me 404. I think I will change my habit by saving my files as .tex. Thanks for your comments.